# Importing a client certificate (with chain) on all service fabric cluster nodes for end user communication

Tags: azure-service-fabric, client-certificates, x509certificate2

I have a need to import my partners' X509 client certificates (along with complete chain) on all of my service fabric cluster nodes so that I can validate each incoming request and authenticate each partner based on the client certificate. This means when I import a client certificate, I want the related intermediate certificate (that signed the client certificate) and related root certificate (that signed the intermediate certificate) to be installed automatically into appropriate cert stores such as 'Intermediate Certificate Authorities' and 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' in Local Machine store.

The reason why I want the entire chain stored in appropriate locations in certificate store is because I intend to validate incoming client certificate using X509Chain in System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace in my service authentication pipeline component. The X509Chain seem to depend on the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' store for complete root certificate validation.

There is lot of information on how to secure a) node to node and b) managing client to cluster communication such as this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security. However there is not much information on securing the communication between services (hosted in service fabric cluster) and the end user consumers using client certificates. If I missed this information, please let me know.

I don't have lot of partner client certificates to configure. The number of partners is well within manageable range. Also I can not recreate the cluster every time there is a new partner client certificate to add.

1. Do I need to do leverage
   /ServiceManifest/CodePackage/SetupEntryPoint element in
   SerivceManifest.xml file and write custom code to import partner
   certificates (that are stored in the key vault or else where)? What are the pros
   and cons of this approach?
2. Or is there any other easy way to import partner certificates that satisfies all of my requirements? If
   so, please detailed steps on how to achieve this.

**Update:**
I tried the suggested method of adding client certificates as described in the above [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure#add-a-secondary-certificate-using-resource-manager-powershell) under osProfile section. This seemed pretty straight forward.

To be able to do this, I first needed to push the related certificates (as secrets) in to the associated key vault as described at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm). In this article, it describes (in section "Formatting certificates for Azure resource provider use") how to format the certificate information into a Json format before storing it as secret in key vault. This json has following format for uploading pfx file bytes:

```
{
    "dataType":  "pfx",
    "data":  "base64-encoded-cert-bytes-go-here",
    "password":  "pfx-password"
}
```

However since I am dealing with public portion of client certificates, I am not dealing with pfx files but only base64 cer files in windows (which apparently are same as pem files elsewhere). And there is no password for public portion of certificates. So I changed the Json format to following:

```
{
    "dataType":  "pem",
    "data":  "base64-encoded-cert-bytes-go-here"
}
```

When I invoked New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment with related ARM template with appropriate changes under osProfile section, I am getting following error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:08:11 PM - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets 'nt1vm' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "CertificateImproperlyFormatted",
        "message": "The secret's JSON representation retrieved from 
https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/ClientCert/ba6855f9866644ccb4c436bb2b7675d3 has data type pem which is not 
an accepted certificate type."
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

I also tried using 'cer' data type as shown below:

```
{
    "dataType":  "cer",
    "data":  "base64-encoded-cert-bytes-go-here"
}
```

It also resulted in the same error.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider importing a certificate on all nodes as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure#add-a-secondary-certificate-using-resource-manager-powershell). (Step 5) You can add multiple certificates in specified stores by using ARM templates, that reference Azure Key Vault. Use durability level Silver/Gold, to keep the cluster running during re-deployment.

Be careful with [adding](https://www.google.com/search?q=dangers%20of%20putting%20certificates%20in%20trusted%20root%20authority) certificates in the trusted store.
If a certificate is created by a trusted CA, there's no direct need to put 
anything in the trusted root authorities store (as they are already there).

Validate client certificates using X509Certificate2.[Verify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify(v=vs.110).aspx), unless every client has his own service instance to communicate with.

Comment: 1) I do understand the dangers of placing certs in the trusted store. 2) If you add the certs through ARM, what happens when I need to add one more cert while the cluster is functional?

Comment: this is what the silver/gold level is for, your vmss nodes will be restarted sequentially

Comment: LoekD: Could you please take a look at updated portion of my question?

Comment: The certificate must be in pfx format, an must be stored in a special json format. Other cert formats are not supported.